# Antlr Arrow Syntax

Tags: antlr

I found this syntax in an Antlr [parser for bash](https://github.com/crashub/bash):

```
file_descriptor
    :   DIGIT -> ^(FILE_DESCRIPTOR DIGIT)
    |   DIGIT MINUS -> ^(FILE_DESCRIPTOR_MOVE DIGIT);
```

What does the `->` syntax do?

What is it called such that I can google it to read about it?

The 'Definitive Guide to Antlr4' only has one page about it.  It refers to "lexer command", but it never names the operator.  The usage in the book differs from the usage in the bash parser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In ANTLR3, `->` is used in parser rules and signifies a [tree rewrite rule](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/display/ANTLR3/Tree+construction), which is no longer supported in ANTLR4.

In ANTLR4, the `->` is used in lexer rules and has nothing to do with the old v3 functionality.

Comment: Page 281 of 'Definitive Guide to Antlr4' refers to it as part of a Lexer Command.  Please address that in your answer.